# Having problem with merging image and gif(Inversed(or blue) images) discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, python-imaging-library

```
avatar1 = ctx.author.avatar_url_as(size = 128) #author
avatar2 = member.avatar_url_as(size = 128) #member
gif = Image.open('images\spanking.gif')
#
data = BytesIO(await avatar1.read()) 
pfp = Image.open(data).convert('RGBA')
pfp = pfp.resize((105,105))
pfp = pfp.rotate(-30,fillcolor = 0)
x,y = 166,64
#
data2 = BytesIO(await avatar2.read())
pfp2 = Image.open(data2).convert('RGBA')
pfp2 = pfp2.resize((64,64))
x2,y2 = 173,257
frames = []
for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(gif):
    frame = frame.copy()
    frame.paste(pfp,(x,y),pfp)
    x+=3 # face movenment
    y+=3 #
    frame.paste(pfp2,(x2,y2))
    frames.append(frame)
frames[0].save('probagif1.gif',save_all = True, append_images=frames[1:])
```

[image: This what happens when i save gif]

I was making fun discord bot command with gif, but when i merged image with frames of gif and saved the gif: every image was inversed(or just blue), i'm tried working with PIL save() options like "include_color_table", "palette" and some other thingies but that didn't really help

Comment: ok, this is not inversed I was inconsiderate, because 1st and 2nd image has the same color as the gif(like yellow walls, or blue floor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found and answer on github, thanks to radarhere(https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3629) if someone having the same problem the solution is to convert frame to the same type as the images you merging.

```
for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(gif):
    frame = frame.copy()
    frame = frame.convert('RGBA') # Thats it
    frame.paste(pfp,(x,y),pfp)
    x+=2 # face movenment
    y+=2 #
    frame.paste(pfp2,(x2,y2),pfp2)
    x2-=1 # same
    y2-=1 #
    frames.append(frame)
frames[0].save('probagif1.gif',save_all = True, append_images=frames[1:])
```

**frame = frame.convert('RGBA')** - thats the solution